# How to fixed Manifest merger failed error when trying to implement a library?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add ramotion paper onboarding android, and having the following problem

in my app gradle I have this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.paperonboarding:paper-onboarding:1.1.3'
```

but I'm getting this error

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion given in the error itself? `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"'`

Comment: yes, but then I get this, Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you

You have to migrate android.support to androidx to use com.google.android.material.libraries

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Add above lines in gradle.properties file.

Migrate to Android X by using following way

Go to Refactor---> Migrate to AndroidX ---> click on Migrate button and do refractor.

And import your classes and XML from androidx packages.

for example

Activity :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your library is using androidx and it has the same dependencies as your current project(your project is using old dependencies, it means dependencies previous to androidX). When it tries to merge it launch a conflict because it has different sources from the same dependency. I suggest to update your dependencies of your project to Androidx :)